# Why is imagex-sticky-maximize working in Windows, and not in Linux

Tags: images, image-mode

From [the package imagex](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-imagex), I use the function `imagex-sticky-maximize` to maximize the image files to the current window.

This works like a charm on Windows 7 x64 with Emacs 25.0.50 However, with the same Emacs setup, I'm trying out Linux Ubuntu. I use the latest Emacs snapshot:

```
GNU Emacs 25.0.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.16.7) of 2015-10-28
```

Everything in Emacs works, except the function `imagex-sticky-maximize`. Then I get the error when I want to maximize the image:

```
image+: (file-error Searching for program No such file or directory convert)
```

I see the pictures (JPEG, PNG, everything) in Emacs buffer. So image display works.

When I look in the source code of `imagex-sticky-maximize` in order to understand why this problem arises on Linux, and not on Windows:

```
(defun imagex-sticky-maximize ()
"Maximize the point image to fit the current frame."
(interactive)
(imagex-sticky--convert-image
(lambda (image)
    (imagex--maximize image))))
```

Given the error message, seems the `imagex-sticky--convert-image` could be the culprit. Looking further in the source:

```
(defun imagex-sticky--convert-image (converter)
(catch 'done
    (let (err)
    (condition-case err1
        (let ((display (imagex-sticky--current-ovprop-display)))
            (when display
            (cl-destructuring-bind (image ov) display
                (let ((new (funcall converter image)))
                (plist-put (cdr new) 'imagex-manual-manipulation t)
                (overlay-put ov 'display new))
                (throw 'done t))))
        (error
        (setq err (append err err1))))
    (condition-case err2
        (let ((display (imagex-sticky--current-textprop-display)))
            (when display
            (cl-destructuring-bind (image begin end) display
                (let ((new (funcall converter image)))
                (plist-put (cdr new) 'imagex-manual-manipulation t)
                (imagex--replace-textprop-image begin end new))
                (throw 'done t))))
        (error
        (setq err (append err err2))))
    (when err
        (imagex--message "%s" err))
    (imagex-sticky-fallback this-command))))
```

I see no possible causes that could suggest why this fails on Linux and works on Windows. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the error message clear enough?  The package is missing a program called `convert` which part of imagemagick.

Just install imagemagick on your system.

Comment: How did you know that the program `convert` was part of imagemagick?

Comment: convert is a pretty common program, so Google will help you.  Or you could use the package search of your distribution, e.g. http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: I have read convert, but I thought it was used as verb instead as naming for an application. Thanks for bringing me back on the right track.